# How can I target html element class names instead of elements?

Tags: html, css

I have this code but it targets all `<li>` and `<a>` elements, how can I make it target a class instead of targeting the element?

I want to have the same exact effect.

This is my html & css:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFD750;
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
    <li><a href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
    <li><a href="calculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add class to your HTML, then target them via CSS. ;) If you are that beginner, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to target all `li` `a` elements and only a specific class name, you can have this instead:

```
li a.active {                 // or just a.active {...}
    display: block;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active:hover {
  background-color: #FFD750;
```

---

```
a.active {...}             // or just .active, this will target the class name
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to select your HTML elements in the DOM.

- You can select ids with `#`
- You can select classes with `.`
- You can select all elements with a tag, like `li`

Here is an example:

```html
<li id="first" class="listElement">First element</li>
<li class="listElement active">Second element</li>
```

```css
#first {
    color: red;
}
.active {
    background: yellow;
}
.listElement {
    padding: 5px;
}

li {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: But what I don't understand is how I can target ```li a```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to archive. Do you want to select the `a` element as a child of `li` or do you want to select all elements with a certain class?

Comment: He wanted to terget a class, the question was clear,

Answer (score 0):

You can target any class by using `.<class>`. So you can do something like:

```
  .active {
      <Desired style definition>
   }
```

This will add the styling to all the elements with the class `active`.
Also note if you want to target any element by it's Id then use `#<id>` instead of dot `.<class>`

Comment: hey but do you know how I can implement them on my code

Comment: Well it's hard to predict exact style definition you want on active class but. You can try adding thoes yourself in it as explained. Hope this helps!.  Also never mind my mistakes. First time giving answer from mobile .

Comment: oh don't worry about it. Your really good. But what I don't understand is how I can target ```li a```